# nullable datetime variable not having Add timespan method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

> How to add Timespan to nullable datetime variable?

I want to convert my datetime to following format and pass it to stored procedure as parameter

```
  dtToDate = dtToDate.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59));
sparamToDate.Value = dtToDate .Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Above working fine as `dtToDate` is not nullable

but for nullable datetime variable
I coulkd not able to find method `Add` to use below code and convert my datetime in format
`2013-10-11 23:59:59.000`

```
dtToDate = dtToDate.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59)); NOT WORKING FOR NULLABLE DATETIME :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nullable types aren't *supposed* to support every operation their non-nullable counterpart supports. It simply wraps up an a struct in a way that allows you to treat it as though it can have a value of null. You'd need to test whether the value is null before you attempt to access any of it's members.

You could do this:

```
if (dtToDate.HasValue)
{
    dtToDate = dtToDate.Value.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59));
}
```

Or this:

```
dtToDate = dtToDate.HasValue ? dtToDate.Value.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59)) : dtToDate;
```

But if you really wanted to, you could define an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx), like this:

```
public static DateTime? Add(this DateTime? dt, TimeSpan offset)
{
    return dt.HasValue ? dt.Value.Add(offset) : dt;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
dtToDate = dtToDate.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59));
```

Comment: Not working then also
Error 61 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ashuthinks The answer clearly shows a bespoke extension method that provides this...

Comment: @ashuthinks If you're using my first or second solution, notice the `.Value` in `dtToDate.Value.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59))`. If you're trying to use the third solution, please read up on extension methods and make sure you've implemented it as a static method on a static class, and included the relevant namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call `Add()` on the `Value` property of the `Nullable<DateTime>`:

```
if (dtToDate != null) { dtToDate = dtToDate.Value.Add(someTimeSpan); }
```